# Can i combine an ultrasonic sensor and gps together?

Tags: arduino-uno, gps, tinygps

I need to operate 2 different sensors by Arduino UNO: GPS module and Ultrasonic sensor. I have managed to run each one of them separately and I don't know how to manipulate the code;

### GPS MODULE

```
#include <TinyGPS++.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

static const int RXPin = 4, TXPin = 3;
static const uint32_t GPSBaud = 9600;

// The TinyGPS++ object
TinyGPSPlus gps;

// The serial connection to the GPS device
SoftwareSerial ss(RXPin, TXPin);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  ss.begin(GPSBaud);
}

void loop()
{
  // This sketch displays information 
  // every time a new sentence is correctly encoded.
  while (ss.available() > 0)
  {
    gps.encode(ss.read());
    if (gps.location.isUpdated())
    {
      Serial.print("Latitude= "); 
      Serial.print(gps.location.lat(), 6);
      Serial.print(" Longitude= "); 
      Serial.println(gps.location.lng(), 6);
    }
  }
}
```

#### ULTRASONIC SENSOR

```
// defines pins numbers
const int trigPin = 9;
const int echoPin = 10;

// defines variables
long duration;
int distance;
void setup() 
{
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT); // Sets the trigPin as an Output
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT); // Sets the echoPin as an Input
  Serial.begin(9600); // Starts the serial communication
}

void loop() 
{
  // Clears the trigPin
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);

  // Sets the trigPin on HIGH state for 10 micro seconds
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

  // Reads the echoPin, returns the sound wave travel time in microseconds
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);

  // Calculating the distance
  distance= duration*0.034/2;

  // Prints the distance on the Serial Monitor
  Serial.print("Distance: ");
  Serial.println(distance);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's easy. I have no possibility to try it. But if your code has been working, this will also. (Just copy/paste.) I had to change the while loop into a if block, because I was not sure, if the while blocks for a longer time. It could have been that the GPS sends and sends and sends ... That would block the ultrasonic sensor.

```
#include <TinyGPS++.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

static const int RXPin = 4, TXPin = 3;
static const uint32_t GPSBaud = 9600;

// The TinyGPS++ object
TinyGPSPlus gps;

// The serial connection to the GPS device
SoftwareSerial ss(RXPin, TXPin);

const int trigPin = 9;
const int echoPin = 10;

long duration;
int distance;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  ss.begin(GPSBaud);

  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT); 
}

void loop()
{
  // This sketch displays information 
  // every time a new sentence is correctly encoded.
  if (ss.available() > 0)
  {
    gps.encode(ss.read());
    if (gps.location.isUpdated())
    {
      Serial.print("Latitude= "); 
      Serial.print(gps.location.lat(), 6);
      Serial.print(" Longitude= "); 
      Serial.println(gps.location.lng(), 6);
    }
  }

  // Clears the trigPin
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);

  // Sets the trigPin on HIGH state for 10 micro seconds
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

  // Reads the echoPin, returns the sound wave travel time in microseconds
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);

  // Calculating the distance
  distance= duration*0.034/2;

  // Prints the distance on the Serial Monitor
  Serial.print("Distance: ");
  Serial.println(distance);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your respond and help sir. But i do have some problems in the output. The gps coordinate does not show

Comment: @AfiqAzmii I'd showed you how to combine the two sketches. That's what you have been asking for. I can't tell you, why this doesn't work, because I don't know anything about the setup. I can not see any pictures of your project and the wiring and I have no link to the documentation of both sensors.  I even don't know which one you use. You did also not tell me, if the distance sensor works correctly.  As this is a complete new question, it would be better to add a new question or update the old one. If you add all the information I asked for, someone or me have a better chance to help you.

Comment: A I've seen you had already asked a new question. I'look into it.